# Understanding ffmpeg -benchmark results

Tags: ffmpeg, benchmarking

Adding `-benchmark` flag to `ffmpeg` command resutls with addition of following 2 lines in the shell output:

```
bench: utime=10.125s stime=4.234s rtime=5.606s
bench: maxrss=110080kB
```

The `maxrss` serves to indicate the maximum RAM used during the `ffmpeg` execution. The `utime`, `stime`, `rtime` indicate accordingly:

- user time;
- system time;
- real time.

I tried to understand the meaning of these times from [the source code](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/90aa2a88f98473810bbbf6514a8327ae8ea9208a/fftools/ffmpeg.c) and failed. Please, help.

1. Which of these times indicate how much time was human waiting while the ffpmeg was processing the video?
2. Can this time be seen directly or it's a combination/calculation of these 3 parameters?
3. How it can be for certain videos `utime > rtime` and for others `utime < rtime`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. rtime is the elapsed clock time, so that's the wait time.
2. Direct, from rtime.
3. utime is the sum of processing time across all threads. Since they may operate in parallel, utime can exceed rtime.